# dict in Python object instance doesn't contain the methods of the class

Tags: python, class, dictionary

When an instance of an object is created, its dict does not contain the classes methods. An example would be

```
    class A(object):
        def __init__(self, value):
            self.value = value
        def some_func(self): pass
    instance = A('some_value')
    print(instance.__dict__) #prints { 'value':'some_value }
```

Why doesn't it contain the methods also. I know that printing `A.__dict__` will print a mappingproxy that contains the function, but this doesn't happen for the instance of A.

I have tried researching how the instance methods of a class are mapped. If this is done using dict. I do know that the instance method also has a dict and other predefined attributes.

```
class A(object)
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
    def some_func(self): pass
instance = A('this')
instance.__dict__ # will print {'value':'some_value'}
A.__dict__ # will print a mapping proxy
```

I expected that the results `instance.__dict__` would contain a mapping for all the methods and attributes as key, value pairs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The methods are methods of the class, and not of the instance.

When calling `instance.some_func()`, you are actually calling `A.some_func(instance)`.

To illustrate, I added an attribute to `A` (`classattr = 'foo'`):

```
class A:
    classattr = 'foo'

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def some_func(self):
        return 1


instance = A('this')
print(f'instance dict : {instance.__dict__}')  # will print {'value':'some_value'}
print(f'class dict : {A.__dict__}')  # will print a mapping proxy
```

This attribute **of the class** is then nowhere to be found in `instance.__dict__`:

```
instance dict : {'value': 'this'}
class dict : {'__module__': '__main__', 'classattr': 'foo', '__init__': <function A.__init__ at 0x0000018AAB2A2400>, 'some_func': <function A.some_func at 0x0000018AAB2A2488>, '__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'A' objects>, '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'A' objects>, '__doc__': None}
```